# How do I get the text at a specific line in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` that is X lines long. How do I get the text that is at, say, line 3?

Example: I have this `TextView`

> This is line 1
>
> And this is line 2
>
> And this is line 3

I want to be able to get the `String` at any one of these lines by itself, such as getting the `String` at line 3 would return "And this is line 3". Searching for line breaks is not the solution I need, as it doesn't take into account text wrapping.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `textView.getLayout().getLineStart(int line)` and `getLineEnd` to find the character offsets in the text.

Then you can just use `textView.getText().substring(start, end)` -- or subsequence if you are using Spannables for formatting/etc.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that `TextView` had it's own special layout, though it makes sense. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 13):

Here is some code to supplement the accepted answer:

```
List<CharSequence> lines = new ArrayList<>();
int count = textView.getLineCount();
for (int line = 0; line < count; line++) {
    int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(line);
    int end = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(line);
    CharSequence substring = textView.getText().subSequence(start, end);
    lines.add(substring);
}
```