# Extract a line from an EditText

Tags: android, string, android-widget, android-edittext

How can we extract a line from a multiLine `EditText` ?

I tried this way, but I know that is not a good practice :

```
String street1 = "";
String street2 = "";
EditText streetEt = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.street));
ExtractedText extractedText = new ExtractedText();
ExtractedTextRequest req = new ExtractedTextRequest();
int endOfLineOffset = 0;

req.hintMaxLines = 1;
streetEt.extractText(req, extractedText);
endOfLineOffset = extractedText.partialEndOffset;
street1 = extractedText.toString();
...
```

is there an easier way to do this like looking for `\n` in the string ?

Comment: I'm slightly confused, are you trying to extract the text from the TextView?

Comment: Ah, ignore my answer below then :D I just reread your question sorry

Comment: Actually, you can just use the getText() method, and then search for the \n in THAT string.

Comment: Jack's answer seems good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the text at a specific line in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272614/how-do-i-get-the-text-at-a-specific-line-in-a-textview)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `String.split()`.  Code example:

```
String multiLines = streetEt.getText().toString();
String[] streets;
String delimiter = "\n";

streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);
```

Now you have an array of streets.

Let's say, for example, your `EditText` reads "1st St.\nHighway Rd.\nUniversity Ave." (or is those 3 streets separated by line breaks, instead of you actually seeing `\n`).  Following the code example I provided you,

- `multiLines` becomes "1st St.\nHighway Rd.\nUniversity Ave."
- `streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);` fills the array `streets` with the street names, i.e.

  - streets[0] = "1st St."
  - streets[1] = "Highway Rd."
  - streets[2] = "University Ave."

Comment: This is a much better way to accomplish this than my answer.

Comment: I am trying to use your code to implement search functionality in an edit text in android.But I am unable to search for the next element in my array list.I have also posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670878/how-to-implement-search-on-a-multiline-edit-text-in-android

Comment: This answer is not full. User can input very long sequence and when it reaches end of current line it continues on the next one. So we can have several lines without any new line symbol. Correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273546/1140997

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String text = streetEt.getText();

String firstLine = text.substring(0,text.indexOf("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
String text=editText1.getText().toString().replace("\n", " ").trim();
```