# Get a specific line from a multiple line TextView

Tags: java, android-studio

How to get the specific text from a multiple line TextView in Android Studio and later set the text extracted to another TextView?

Comment: Is there a question? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to get the whole text in a textview. My question is how to get a specific line in that text view. Cos i have 1 textview with multiple lines

Comment: I have tried to get whole text from textview. What i want to do is to get a specific line from that text view since my text view is multiple line. For example i want to get the 2nd line of the text view.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272614/how-do-i-get-the-text-at-a-specific-line-in-a-textview/6273546#6273546), generally you should do something like this:

```
//find the character offsets in the text
    int startPos = myTextView.getLayout().getLineStart(linenumber);
    int endPos = myTextView.getLayout().getLineEnd(linenumber);

    String theLine = myTextView.getText().substring(startPos, endPos);
```

Then set this specific line to your other `TextView`.

Comment: It gives an error with ".substring" and it should be CharSequence substring = textView.getText().subSequence(start, end); instead, but not parseble it says. I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
textView.getLayout().getLineStart(int line)
```

and
 **getLineEnd** to find the character offsets in the text.

Then you can just use

```
textView.getText().substring(start, end)
```

or subsequence if you are using Spannables for formatting/etc.