# Kotlin android - get row from multiline textview

Tags: android, kotlin

Im starting to learn Kotlin and android development but have a question for which I cant find an answer online.

I have a multiline textview with 4 lines/rows in it. 
How do I access 2nd line/row?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272614/how-do-i-get-the-text-at-a-specific-line-in-a-textview

Comment: Thank you for prompt response, been scratching my head for a while now.

Comment: Hopefully it helped.