# Is it possible to calculate the maximum no of characters that can fit inside a textview of fixed width and fixed no of lines

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textview

I have a TextView in my layout which has a width set to match_parent and height set as wrap_content. The layout has a padding of say 10dp, textSize as 15sp and noofLines as 2. I would like to calculate the maximum no of letters that can fit this specific textView.

Comment: You could approximate since not all characters have the same width.

Comment: Probably makes more sense to use - android:maxLength="65" instead of calculating the max number of characters to be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find android TextView number of characters per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970640/how-to-find-android-textview-number-of-characters-per-line)

Comment: You could rewrite TextView, in the custom TextView to implement a calculation method, get the number of lines with the maximum number of words per line, I wrote a simple custom TextView, do you need me to add to the answer.

Comment: @LeoZhu Sure. Would be a reference to start with.

Comment: could it work ？

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Custom TextView:

```
public class MyTextView : AppCompatTextView
{
    public MyTextView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public int GetEstimatedLength()
    {
        int height = Height;
        int lineHeight =LineHeight;
        int linecount = height / lineHeight;

        float textSize = TextSize;
        float linewords = Width / textSize;
        return (int)(linecount * (int)linewords);

    }
}
```

then in your axml:

```
<MyTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textSize="31sp"
    android:id="@+id/myTextView1" />
```

finally in the activity :

```
MyTextView myTextView = FindViewById<MyTextView>(Resource.Id.myTextView1);
int numbers = myTextView.GetEstimatedLength();
```

"numbers" is the maximum number of characters，it has no effect on the sign